# Imputing null values in spark dataframe, based on the row category, by fetching the values from another dataframe in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So i have a dataframe as shown below, that has been stored as a temporary view by the name `mean_value_gn5` so that i can query using `sql()`, whenever i need to fetch the data.

```
+-------+----+
|Species|Avgs|
+-------+----+
|    NO2|  43|
|    NOX|  90|
|     NO|  31|
+-------+----+
```

This dataframe stores the categorical average of the 'Species' rounded off to the nearest whole number using the `ceil()` function. I need to use these categorical averages to impute the missing values of column `Value` in my dataframe of interest `clean_gn5`. I created a new column `Value_imp` which would hold my final column with the imputed values.

I made an attempt to do so as follows:

```
clean_gn5 = clean_gn5.withColumn("Value_imp",
      when($"Value".isNull, sql("Select Avgs from mean_value_gn5 where Species = "+$"Species").select("Avgs").head().getLong(0).toInt)
        .otherwise($"Value"))
```

The above mentioned code runs, but the values are getting incorrectly imputed i.e. for the row containing `Species` as `NO` the value getting imputed is `43` instead of `31`.

Prior to doing this I first checked if i was able to fetch the values correctly by executing the following:

```
println(sql("Select Avgs from mean_value_gn5 where Species = 'NO'").select("Avgs").head().getLong(0))
```

I am able to fetch the value correctly after hardcoding the `Species` and as per my understanding `$"Species"` should help me fetch the value corresponding to the `Species` column for that particular row.

Also I thought that probably i was missing the single quotes around the hardcoded `Species` value i.e. `'NO'`. So I tried doing the following

```
 clean_gn5 = clean_gn5.withColumn("Value_imp",
      when($"Value".isNull, sql("Select Avgs from mean_value_gn5 where Species = '"+$"Species"+"'").select("Avgs").head().getLong(0).toInt)
        .otherwise($"Value"))
```

But that resulted in the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
```

I am fairly new to Spark and Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `clean_gn5` contains the data

```
+-------+-----+
|Species|Value|
+-------+-----+
|    NO2|  2.3|
|    NOX|  1.1|
|     NO| null|
|    ABC|  4.0|
|    DEF| null|
|    NOX| null|
+-------+-----+
```

Joining `clean_gn5` with  `mean_value_gn5` using a left join will result in

```
+-------+-----+----+
|Species|Value|Avgs|
+-------+-----+----+
|    NO2|  2.3|  43|
|    NOX|  1.1|  90|
|     NO| null|  31|
|    ABC|  4.0|null|
|    DEF| null|null|
|    NOX| null|  90|
+-------+-----+----+
```

On this dataframe you can apply per row the logic you have already given in your question and the result is (after dropping the Avgs column):

```
+-------+-----+---------+
|Species|Value|Value_imp|
+-------+-----+---------+
|    NO2|  2.3|      2.3|
|    NOX|  1.1|      1.1|
|     NO| null|     31.0|
|    ABC|  4.0|      4.0|
|    DEF| null|     null|
|    NOX| null|     90.0|
+-------+-----+---------+
```

The code:

```
clean_gn5.join(mean_value_gn5, Seq("Species"), "left")
  .withColumn("Value_imp", when('value.isNull, 'Avgs).otherwise('value))
  .drop("Avgs")
  .show()
```